# reconfigure LXD subnet for canonical-kubernetes on Ubuntu 16.04 with LXD

Tags: 16.04, networking, lxd, kubernetes

We have set up canonical-kubernetes and got a private docker registry running with self signed certificates and an ingress.

Now we would like to make this cluster available on our corporate network.

My boss has asked that we choose a specific range for the network bridge to use.

I can reconfigure the LXD network with

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -p medium lxd
```

however I'm wondering if this will break my canonical-kubernetes cluster.

**Is there a way I could rebuild it with the new subnet or do I need to destroy it and recreate it?**

If so what comands would I run? Would it be better to start over with a clean install?

Thanks for your help. 
Brian

Answer (score 0):

I successfully set the network using the lxc command like this: `sudo lxc network set ipv4.address 10.10.10.1/24`

Command reference: https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/master/doc/networks.md

Relevant Ubuntu blogpost: https://blog.ubuntu.com/2017/02/14/network-management-with-lxd-2-3